# Automatic Label Resize in UICollectionViewCell Not Working

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am having trouble getting a label in a UICollectionViewCell to dynamically resize based on length of string. I have subclassed the cell and linked the label to it. I have set the number of lines to 0 and still not dice.

I also call the sizeToFit() method.

Compiling for iOS 8.2

Here is my custom Cell code:

```
class ItemCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var reviewerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var statusImageView: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.selected = false

    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... So thank you to those who have helped. I have found out that my issue was indeed related to Auto-Layout constraints. I simply missed the box that said "Constrain to Margin".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you didn't uncheck `Autoresize subviews` in InterfaceBuilder:

[image]

Comment: I do have the AutoSize Subviews checkbox checked. :-/

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the collection view what size the cell should be. Use this method of the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol:

```
collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:
```

You can calculate the size by calling NSString UIKit Additions's method

```
boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:
```

and passing the font information in the attributes argument.

Comment: That unfortunately did not work either. It is simply a text label inside of a collection view cell that is not resizing not the entire cell.

Comment: It works in all of my projects where I have dynamic collection view cells. Show how you implemented it by editing your question.

Comment: I am a little confused as to why I am trying to resize the cell and not the label that is the subview of the cell? I am able to resize and adjust the layout of the cell just fine... it is simply the text label inside of the cell that is not adjusting for the length of string

Comment: Or perhaps as a better question... can you not use auto-layout constraints if I want the label to dynamically resize?

Comment: If you implement the cell size correctly with the delegate and the auto layout constraints are correctly set up to position the label in the cell's `contentView`, it should just work.